# Magento Order Comments

Tags: magento-1.7

And i have this form in the url link checkout/cart, and in this page i have a forms which has the following textbox of your name your email your telephone number your comments your company and your deadline project. In this form it works well and the data will send to email. I want that the your comments data will send to the admin panel in the sales/orders. Which is on this path `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view` info.phtml file.
I have found a sample code and im using it. And ive found out that the sample code im looking doesnt work out. This is the reference link im using 
http://www.magecorner.com/magento-order-comments/

can someone help me figured this thing out? ive been stuck in here since last week 
Any help is muchly appreciated

Comment: What is the error that causes? Firstly, is ur extension configured properly?? In the above link they are using observer. So is that observer gets called when the event generated? If any one of the above works, then we can help u something..

Comment: ummm i think the code has no errors but my main problem here is i have a form in the checkout/cart page and all the data in the form were passed and sends to email and i want the comments data will be passed in sales/order in admin panel :(

Comment: here in the red line box this is the checkout/cart page i want that the comments data will be passed to sales/order in admin panel
http://awesomescreenshot.com/07641p98d4

Comment: Did u check that is ur comments gets stored to DB or not?

Comment: i dont know if it stored in the DB or not hmmmmm

Comment: can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by using events. Add the below code to your config.xml. I hope you have an idea of dealing with observer and events.

```
<events>
  <sales_order_place_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
    <observers>
      <sales_order_place_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
        <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
        <class>orderaudit/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
        <method>orderPlaced</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
        <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
      </sales_order_place_after_handler>
    </observers>
  </sales_order_place_after>
  <sales_order_payment_capture> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
    <observers>
      <sales_order_payment_capture_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
        <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
        <class>orderaudit/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
        <method>paymentCapture</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
        <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
      </sales_order_payment_capture_handler>
    </observers>
  </sales_order_payment_capture>
  <sales_order_creditmemo_refund> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
    <observers>
      <sales_order_creditmemo_refund_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
        <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
        <class>orderaudit/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
        <method>creditmemoRefund</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
        <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
      </sales_order_creditmemo_refund_handler>
    </observers>
  </sales_order_creditmemo_refund>
</events>
```

Step 2: Now add the following to `Observer.php`

```
public function orderPlaced(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        //if admin
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
            $username = $user->getUser()->getUsername();
            $comment = "Order placed by <strong>".$username."</strong>";
            $order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment)
                ->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)
                ->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
                $order->save();
        }
        else {
        //placed by customer online
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order placed online by customer')
                ->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)
                ->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
            $order->save();
        }
    }
public function paymentCapture(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
    $order = $invoice->getOrder();
    $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $username = $user->getUser()->getUsername();
    $comment = "Payment captured by <strong>".$username."</strong>";
    $order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment)
        ->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)
        ->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
    $order->save();
}
public function creditmemoRefund(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $creditmemo = $observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo();
    $order = $creditmemo->getOrder();
    $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $username = $user->getUser()->getUsername();
    $comment = "Refund by <strong>".$username."</strong>";
    $order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment)
        ->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)
        ->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
    $order->save();

}
```

}